# VB can't string to arraylist when read from file

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

Either I'm missing something really obvious or something about vb is really messed up.  I'm trying to read in from a file and add the lines to an arraylist... pretty simple   If I add strings to the arraylist this way

```
selectOptions.Add("Standard")
selectOptions.Add("Priority")
selectOptions.Add("3-Day")
selectOptions.Add("Overnight")
```

I have no problems

But when I do this it appears to end up empty which makes no sense to me.

```
Dim reader As StreamReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(path)
    Dim line As String
    Do
        line = reader.ReadLine
        selectOptions.Add(line)
    Loop Until line Is Nothing
    reader.Close()
```

Messagebox.show line all day so I know it is reading the file and the file isn't empty and I have checked the type of line which comes back as string.  This makes no sense to me.

Comment: Where do you observe the empty ArrayList? And why not use List(Of String)?

Comment: Also: the last time through the loop you'll add a null/Nothing string to the list.

Comment: That code works for me.  I would check file permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking for `reader.EndOfStream` in a While loop will probably work better:

```
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(path)
    Dim line As String
    While Not reader.EndOfStream
        line = reader.ReadLine
        selectOptions.Add(line)
    End While
    reader.Close()
```

You can also get an exception if selectOptions isn't declared as a `New ArrayList`, if you properly have all your Options turned On.

Another thing to remember, if your code is in the form's Load Handler, it won't throw an exception it will just break out of the handler routine and load the form.  This makes it  really hard to find things like bad file names, badly declared objects, etc.

One thing I do is put suspect code in a button's Click handler and see what exceptions it throws there.

Of course this could all be moot if you use the File.ReadAllLines method and add it directly to the ArrayList:

```
selectOptions.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(path))
```

Comment: The ReadLine method will return null (Nothing) at the end of the file.    For a blank line, it will return String.Empty so the loop will not exit.